# How to formatting a monetary value with ICU hiding the minor units if zero

Tags: zend-framework2, number-formatting, icu, currency-formatting

I'm trying to format a currency value with Zend's CurrencyFormat (using ICU). Basically it's working - the pattern `#,##0.#` outputs a correct format like
`1.200,00 €`.

Is it possible to leave out the minor unit part if it's zero just by modifying the pattern? I want to have the following formatting results:

- `1.200 €` if minor units are ".00"
- `1.200,34 €` if minour units are not ".00"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to achieve it by modifying pattern. I mean, you can check if provided number is type of `float` or `int`. If it's `int` you can set different pattern, but there is simpler way (more recommended way IMO).
3rd argument of `__invoke()` method is `$showDecimal`. It takes bool value. If you want decimals to be visible- pass `true` (it's default value), `false` otherwise.

**Example**
`true` - if number is integer

```
<?php echo $this->currencyFormat(1234, "EUR", true, "de_DE"); ?>
```

Output:

`1.234,00 €`

`false` - if number is float

```
<?php echo $this->currencyFormat(1234, "EUR", false, "de_DE"); ?>
```

Output:

`1.234 €`

**Loop example**

```
// $prices = [1234, 1234.23, 234, 3456.54]
<?php foreach($prices as $price): ?>
    <?php $showDecimal = is_float($price) ? true : false;
    <p><?php echo $this->currencyFormat(1234, "EUR", $showDecimal, "de_DE"); ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Global**
If for some reason you want hide decimal numbers for all currencies/formats, you can use `setShouldShowDecimals()` method:

```
$this->plugin("currencyformat")->setShouldShowDecimals(false)->setCurrencyCode("USD")->setLocale("en_US");

echo $this->currencyFormat(1234.00);  // "$1,234"
```

Here is a list of all available symbols for pattern http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#details

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already did some tests with the `$showDecimal` setting, but unfortunately it's only a "off-for-all-cases" or "on-for-all-cases". Right now I'm string-replacing ",00" with an empty string. Not nice but at least it works.

Comment: I have edited my post. I don't know how your data looks like, but can't you check if numer has decimal places like in my "loop example"? I think it would be more elegant way then using `str_replace`

Comment: The price is defined in minor units (e.g. 123456 is $1234.56 in the end). So I guess the only way is to check if it ends with "00" and set `$showDecimal` accordingly or to just replace ".00" with an empty string in the end.

Comment: Do `is_float($price / 100) ? true : false`. 123456/100 returns `float`, while 123400/100 returns `int`

Comment: That's true - however, it seems it's not possible just by defining the pattern :-(